# C style cast when specifying callback function?

Tags: c++, casting, win32gui

When calling the Win32 function EnumWindows, which of the following is correct:

```
EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC(MyCallback), 0);
```

or

```
EnumWindows(reinterpret_cast<WNDENUMPROC>(MyCallback), 0);
```

Thanks,
Nic.

Comment: It depends on the type of `MyCallback`. If you need a cast at all, then there's something scary happening, and you're probably causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you'll define MyCallback exactly as MSDN says - `BOOL CALLBACK MyCallback( HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam )` - then you don't need any cast at all